# button top right of image

Tags: css, flexbox, bulma

Using Bulma framework, I'm trying to put a button at the top right of the image, but it's only showing at the bottom of the image.
I tried to use justify-content and flex, but the button is still at the bottom

```css
.justify-content-start {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<figure class="image is-128x128">
  <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/256x256.png">
</figure>
<a class="delete is-medium justify-content-start" style="display:flex-row;"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the Bulma framework so maybe there is a way to achieve it using framework's classes, I let you search in the framework documentation.

But here is a working exemple to explain you the idea:

You need to use the `z-index` CSS property whitch allow you to specify the level of an element regarding an other element (superposition).

For this to works, each elements need to have a `position` to (z-index needs it).

So I wrapp the two elements (the figure and the button) inside a "container" with a "relative" position ([more info about CSS position](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp)).

Then I had a position relative to the figure too (because it wont move, I just need it to set the z-index), and a z-index to 1.

Finally, the button get the "absolute" position (relative the closest wrapping element with a position: in our exemple it will be the "container", that's his purpose), and a z-index of 3 (greater than the image to it will be display on to p of it).
When just set the position on top/right and voilà!

**Important note:** I HAD to add the `!important` marker to force my parameters other the ones set by the framework in order to make it works as intended (This is just for the exemple, I strongly encourage you to search if the documentation offer an alternative). Or maybe someone who actually know the framework can add answer you too.

Anyway I believe understanding how CSS works can't hurt.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 128px;
}

.back-element {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.front-element {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 5px !important;
  right: 5px !important;
  z-index: 3 !important;
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <figure class="image is-128x128 back-element">
    <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/256x256.png">
  </figure>
  <a class="delete is-medium front-element"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not what I meant, but your solution turned out to be better, and really nice. I think I'll adapt it! I simply wanted it to the top and to the right of the image, not inside of it, however, this one looks great also. Even though I like this idea and will probably use it, perhaps you know the solution to the original problem? Just because I've been trying to solve it for a long time now.

Comment: The button is inside because I add a decalage to the top/right position of 5px, but you can set it to 0 or ethen a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the button inside the **figure** tag and give it css property "position: **absolute**".

It could look something like this:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<figure class="image is-128x128">
  <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/256x256.png">
  <a class="delete is-medium" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;"></a>
</figure>
```

Of course, external css style in a class is preferable.

Comment: I wanted it to be shorter and removed the bulma import, it is fixed now.